# Why does Rsync of tree structure into root break filesystem on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, rsync

I have developed an application which I am trying to install on raspberry pi via a script.  The directory structure I have is this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $ tree files.rpi/

files.rpi/
├── etc
│   └── config
│       └── inetdrm
├── lib
│   └── systemd
│       └── system
│           └── inetdrm.service
└── usr
    └── local
        └── bin
            └── inetdrm
```

When I try to install the tree structure onto the pi with this **install.sh:** script

```
#! /bin/bash
FILES="./files.rpi"
sudo rsync -rlpt "$FILES/" /
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/inetdrm.service
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/inetdrm
#sudo systemctl start inetdrm.service
#sudo systemctl enable inetdrm.service
```

The filesystem on the pi breaks.  I loose all access to commands, the script fails, as shown on this transcript.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $ ./install.sh 
./install.sh: line 4: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 5: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $ ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $ pwd
/home/pi/inetdrm
pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $ ls /
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $
```

Rebooting the pi results in kernel panic due to no init.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I don't know why it'd cause that problem, although I would expect it to mess up permissions on existing directories. I'd suggest running `rsync` with `--dry-run` first next time. BTW, I'd expect `~/root/` to expand to something like `/home/pi/root/`, and I don't think that's where you want to install the files.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @GordonDavisson. The reference to /home/pi/root was a left over from some experiments to ensure that I was actually writing the files I thought I was.  I've edited my OP with the correct line (rsync to /) .  For the record, everything works fine when I rsync to "/home/pi/root",  it breaks when I rsync to the filesystem root ("/").

Comment: A guess: your `./files.rpi/lib` has permissions like `0700` or `0750`.  The `-p` flag on `rsync` would set the permissions of `/lib` to be the same, I suspect, but would leave it owned by `root`.  That means nothing in `/lib` can be accessed by you, and since all shared libraries are there, no binaries can run.

Comment: High praise for the the sound reasoning @NateEldredge. but: pi@raspberrypi:~/inetdrm $ ls -ld files.rpi/lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Jan 12 11:32 files.rpi/lib

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Turns out Rsync is not the right tool for the job. My solution was to deploy with the script below. Before writing the files to the target destination, it checks if the file contents are different. So it won't overwrite if the files are already there. You could even run this automatically on every reboot.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILES="files.rpi"

deploy_dir () {
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob

    for SRC in "${1}"/*; do

        # Strip files dir prefix to get destination path
        DST="${SRC#$FILES}"

        if [ -d "${SRC}" ]; then
            if [ -d "${DST}" ]; then
                # Destination directory already exists,
                # go one level deeper
                deploy_dir "${SRC}"
            else
                # Destination directory doesn't exist,
                # copy SRC dir (including contents) to DST
                echo "${SRC} => ${DST}"
                cp -r "${SRC}" "${DST}"
            fi
        else
            # Only copy if contents aren't the same
            # File attributes (owner, execution bit etc.) aren't considered by cmp!
            # So if they change somehow, this deploy script won't correct them
            cmp --silent "${SRC}" "${DST}" || echo "${SRC} => ${DST}" && cp "${SRC}" "${DST}"
        fi
    done
}

deploy_dir "${FILES}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so after a good nights sleep, I worked out what is going on.

Rsync doesn't just do a simple copy or replace operation.  It first makes a temporary copy of what it is replacing, and then moves that temporary copy into place.  When doing a folder merge, it seems it does something similar causing (in my case) all the binaries in the /usr/* tree to be replaced while some are still in use.

**The solution:**
use `--inplace`
ie:

```
sudo rsync --inplace -rlpt "$FILES/" /
```

which causes rsync to work on the files (and directories, it seems) in their existing location rather than doing a copy-and-move.

I have tested the solution and confirmed it works, but I can not find any explicit mention of how rsync handles directory merge without the --inplace flag, so if someone can provide more info, that'd be great.

**UPDATE:** I found that when using --inplace the issue still occurs if rsync is interrupted for some reason.  I'm not entirely certain about the inner workings of directory merge in rsync, so I have concluded that it may not be the best tool for this job.  Instead I wrote my own deployment function.  Here it is in case anyone stumbling across this post finds it useful:

```
#! /bin/bash
FILES="files.rpi"

installFiles(){
  FILELIST=$(find "$1" -type f)
  for SRC in $FILELIST; do
    DEST="/$(echo "$SRC"| cut -f 2- -d/)"
    DIR=$(dirname "$DEST")
    if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
      sudo mkdir -p "$DIR"
    fi
    echo "$SRC => $DEST"
    sudo cp "$SRC" "$DEST"
  done
}

installFiles "$FILES"
```

Comment: When updating files in Linux, the standard process is to USE a temporary file. Linux does not allow "inplace" update of a binary file while it is executing. This will cause as "text file busy" error message. Furthermore, doing 'inplace" update of config file will result in the file being in inconsistent state during the transfer (See: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync). Consider reviewing the `inetdrm` logic).